# How to allow cors on loopback 4?

Tags: node.js, loopback4

I need to allow cors on my loopback 4 server.
I need my apis available for calls from a different domain.
How can I do that on loopback 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is only one of many ways to explicitly configure cors:

In index.ts (or whatever your entrypoint is) you can manually set cors config in the options before passing them into your App.

```
  options.rest.cors = {origin: "mydomain.com,myotherdomain.com", methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTION', preflightContinue: false,  credentials: true};
```

EG (here we are setting the hosts through an env variable):

```
export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {

  // configure cors
  options.rest.cors = {origin: process.env.CORS_HOST, methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTION', preflightContinue: false,  credentials: true};
  
  const app = new MyApplication(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, CORS is enabled by https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest/src/rest.server.ts#L208.

The CORS can be set in Rest config - https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Server.html

```
{
  rest: {
    cors: {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything about any rest config on that page.... such an important thing as CORS, you would think there would be many examples and tutorials about it

Comment: @Demiro-FE-Architect: I found it here instead - [https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Customizing-server-configuration.html](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Customizing-server-configuration.html)

Answer (score -1):

By default. CORS is fully enabled in loopback
In advanced, you can modify your configuration by following this link https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Server.html

Answer (score -1):

Replace whole sequence.ts file to:

```
import {MiddlewareSequence} from '@loopback/rest';

export class MySequence extends MiddlewareSequence {}
```

Comment: Was your answer referring to this comment?
https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/issues/5368#issuecomment-626234170